# How to delete default VPCs from multiple aws accounts using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, vpc

How can I delete the default VPCs from multiple AWS accounts using terraform?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with Terraform, use https://github.com/gruntwork-io/cloud-nuke or any similar tool. be aware that this tool can delete everything in an AWS account, so for default VPC, you need to pass the correct option.

Answer (score 1):

We've added support for this to our `cloudposse/awsutils` provider by using the [`awsutils_default_vpc_deletion`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudposse/awsutils/latest/docs/resources/awsutils_default_vpc_deletion) resource so we can better automate for compliance/remediation. Note, this intentionally violates the principle that  `terraform` should only manage objects that it created.

Comment: It only deletes the VPC in the **current** region rather than all regions. We'd have to copy-paste the block of code for each region? Plus, when Amazon launches a new region in the future, we'd have to do another copy-and-paste.

I ended up using this nifty shell script (unrelated to terraform): https://gist.github.com/jokeru/e4a25bbd95080cfd00edf1fa67b06996

Whenever Amazon launches a new region, I can just re-run the shell script "as is", no further copy-and-paste needed.

BTW, if you insist on terraform, I suppose you can run the shell script in a `local-exec`.

Comment: > It only deletes the VPC in the current region rather than all regions.
 
That's a terraform convention. A provider block should be specified for each region and then the alias of the provider should be passed to the resource. To be clear, this is how all terraform providers should be implemented appropriately and it's not a limitation of the resource or provider.

https://www.terraform.io/language/providers/configuration#provider-configuration-1

Answer (score 0):

Natively in Terraform this cannot be achieved, however I have been able to run it from Terraform, but it is very hacky, and took an age to get right.

I used a `resource "null_resource" "delete-vpc" {` which runs a `#!/bin/bash` script to iterate over all regions in an account, and use the aws cli to find the default VPC's and remove them